# How to download subtitles from pluzz.fr

Tags: text, video-streaming, television, subtitle

Is there a way to download subtitles/closed captions from pluzz fr or the beta version, http://pluzz.francetv.fr, please?

Here's an example video that comes with closed captioning (Tout le monde veut prendre sa place): http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/tout_le_monde_veut_prendre_sa_place_,69573658.html

By the way, you'll need a French IP to watch the video.

Regards.

Comment: Of course I've already tried the YouTube CC extraction methods with Pluzz, but no luck.

Comment: I really don't know why someone would vote this one down, but there's literally nothing to be found on the whole internet about it.

Comment: This web is about programming. You have to use Yahoo Answers or something else. If you are asking about "I'm trying to program something to download subtitles in c++/php/ruby/etc... this is what I have but I'm stuck here/this line throws an error" is ok, but not this.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Well, answering this question requires a knowledge of programming indeed, so I think it's a valid one. By the way, I found a similar question on the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036796/how-to-extract-subtitles-from-youtube-videos Needless to say, there are (and had been by the time the question was posted) loads of web pages covering the issue, but the question was voted up and answered as well.

Comment: Sometimes off-topic questions are answered. This post is flagged as off-topic. StackOverflow is part of a network of 88 answers sites, you can check the sites here http://stackexchange.com/sites and select the one that fits your needings, maybe you are answered faster than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into this as well and have made some progress. To update your example, (to a video that is available for the next 6 days) I've used http://pluzz.francetv.fr/videos/tout_le_monde_veut_prendre_sa_place_,70697467.html

Using the ID number at the end of that URL, go to this URL to get the XML-like info file about that program i.e. www.pluzz.fr/appftv/webservices/video/getInfosOeuvre.php?mode=zeri&id-diffusion=70697467

If you look in that resulting file, you will see various into about the program including at the end: incrust type="accessibilite". If subtitles are available, this is followed by a relative URL pointing to the subtitle file. For this example, you can see:

```
<incrust type="accessibilite">/appftv/webservices/video/getFichierSmi.php?smi=france2/70697467.smi&source=azad</incrust>
```

Prefix that relative link with the pluzz website, and the result is: http://www.pluzz.fr/appftv/webservices/video/getFichierSmi.php?smi=france2/70697467.smi&source=azad

which which provides you with the subtitles in SAMI format (file extension .smi). This is an XML like subtitle format, but I haven't (yet!) found any player that can correctly display them nor found an easy way to convert them into a clean SRT format. However, I do think it would be a relatively simple task (for someone with some programming skills) to convert it into SRT format, but that isn't me...  Perhaps the OP has those skills and can take it from here??

PS. Also of interest is the fact that you don't need a French IP to access the info file or the subtitles file, just the video file.